# Apache Curator and ZooKeeper Observer Nodes

Tags: apache-zookeeper, apache-curator

Folks,

We are using Apache Curator to access an ZooKeeper ensemble (A,B,C)

CuratorFrameworkFactory.newClient(zookeeperConnectionString, retryPolicy)

We recently added two new Observer Nodes (D,E) to this ensemble. Now our zookeeperConnectionString has A,B,C,D,E

Question - Does Curator has the smarts to always read / write from the Observer node provided in the connect String ?. (or) does it randomly pick a member in the zookeeperConnectionString (or) does it default to the Observer.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The Curator/zookeeper client randomly picks a member from the connection string. The zookeeper server internally syncs the info among the members of the ensemble.